# Variable density in the equation of motion

Tags: physics, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

At a fixed point in time, consider the equation of motion
$$
\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol \sigma(u) + \boldsymbol f
= \rho \ddot{\boldsymbol u} \quad \text{in $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^d$}
$$
for a displacement $\boldsymbol u$, a stress tensor $\boldsymbol\sigma(\boldsymbol u)$, an outer force $\boldsymbol f$ and a density $\rho$. Testing this equation with functions $\boldsymbol v \in X = H^1(\Omega)^d$ yields the equation
$$
\int_\Omega \langle \rho \ddot{\boldsymbol u}, \boldsymbol v\rangle
+ \int_\Omega \langle \boldsymbol \sigma(u), \nabla\boldsymbol v\rangle
= \int_\Omega \langle \boldsymbol f, \boldsymbol v \rangle
- \int_{\partial \Omega} \langle \boldsymbol \sigma \boldsymbol n, \boldsymbol v\rangle
\quad \forall \boldsymbol v \in X
$$
To derive a weak formulation now, in particular, one needs to determine what space $\ddot{\boldsymbol u}$ should lie in. If we simply set $\rho = 1$, then the answer is trivial and given by $\ddot{\boldsymbol u} \in X^*$, where the corresponding integral is reinterpreted as a duality bracket.

**Q: What if we are dealing with a density $\rho$ that varies in space, though?**

*Positive results*: If we assume $\rho X \subset X$, which should e.g. be the case whenever $\rho \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$, then we can define
$$\langle \rho \ddot{\boldsymbol u}, \boldsymbol v\rangle_{(X, X^*)} := \langle \ddot{\boldsymbol u}, \rho \boldsymbol v\rangle_{(X, X^*)}$$
*Negative results*: The regularity of $\rho \boldsymbol v$ can be as bad as the regularity of $\rho$ (since $\boldsymbol v$ can be a constant function), so that we must have $\rho \in H^1(\Omega)$.

In summary, the way I see it, we can choose

- $\ddot{\boldsymbol u} \in X^*$, which restricts $\rho$ to a space like $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ or
- $\ddot{\boldsymbol u} \in L^2(\Omega)^d$, which allows for arbitrary $\rho \in L^\infty(\Omega)$.

Is this issue discussed anywhere?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by $\rho X \subset \rho$. Did you mean $\rho X \subset X$?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: Yes I did. Thanks for pointing that out.